# Robolectric 3.0 returns null pointer

Tags: java, android, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I am trying to upgrade Robolectric to 3.0. I am using `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` and also added `@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)` above my test class. I have also tried using `testCompile org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1-SNAPSHOT`. Below is the stack trace I am seeing in the logs.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.res.builder.DefaultPackageManager.metaDataToBundle(DefaultPackageManager.java:725)
    at org.robolectric.res.builder.DefaultPackageManager.addManifest(DefaultPackageManager.java:503)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:80)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:440)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:244)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:185)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Added code formatting to stack trace for readability.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. Cannot tell that I know what did cause them, but my gradle unit tests are working if my testclass is annotated with

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(emulateSdk = 19, constants = BuildConfig.class)
```

Please try to run it from the console with `gradle testCompile`

Comment: I am running from the command line with this command:                  ./gradlew testDebug -Dpre-dex=false --info --stacktrace                                  I am still seeing the same issue.